# Why use large numbers directly in your code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers

If you look at GA(google analytics), 268435455, 2147483647 will do bit operations with these numbers.

AirBnB Also use these numbers and bitwise operators: 3266489909, 2246822507, 3864292196.

example)

```
function n(e, t) {
    return (65535 & e) * t + (((e >>> 16) * t & 65535) << 16) & 4294967295
}

function r(e) {
    for (var t = e.length, r = 3432918353, o = 461845907, i = 0, u = void 0, a = t & -4, c = 0; c < a; c += 4) u = e.charCodeAt(c) | e.charCodeAt(c + 1) << 8 | e.charCodeAt(c + 2) << 16 | e.charCodeAt(c + 3) << 24, u = n(u, r), u = u << 15 | u >>> 17, u = n(u, o), i ^= u, i = i << 13 | i >>> 19, i = 5 * i + 3864292196 | 0;
    switch (u = 0, t % 4) {
        case 3:
            u = e.charCodeAt(a + 2) << 16;
        case 2:
            u |= e.charCodeAt(a + 1) << 8;
        case 1:
            u |= e.charCodeAt(a), u = n(u, r), u = u << 15 | u >>> 17, u = n(u, o), i ^= u
    }
    return i ^= t, i ^= i >>> 16, i = n(i, 2246822507), i ^= i >>> 13, i = n(i, 3266489909), i ^= i >>> 16, i >>> 0
}
```

I am wondering why it works in this way.

Comment: `268435455..toString(2) === '1111111111111111111111111111'`

Comment: 100101 ... does the binary code in the long decimal number mean ?.?

Comment: `268435455 === (1 << 28) - 1`. Magic numbers are generally acceptable in bit-manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

**268435455** is an odd composite number. It is composed of six distinct prime numbers multiplied together. It has a total of sixty-four divisors.

Prime factorization of 268435455:
3 × 5 × 29 × 43 × 113 × 127

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647_(number)), the number **2147483647** is the eighth [Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime), equal to 2^31 − 1. It is one of only four known [double Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Mersenne_number). This is the maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer in computing. The nice part about the number is that 2,147,483,647 remained the largest known prime until 1867.

Similarly other numbers also have the relevant significance in computing.

Answer (score 0):

The first two numbers are [bitwise `AND` masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)). Google Analytics is trying to extract a specific number of bits from a number:

```
00001111 11111111 11111111 11111111 = 268435455
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 = 2147483647
00001111 11100000 00000000 00000000 = 266338304
```

Essentially, it only wants bits where there is a `1` bit—it wants to ignore the `0` bits.
It's part of their domain URL hash code.

---

Those other numbers are [mathematical constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constant) used in the hashing algorithm **[MurmurHash3](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3)**. Basically they have been statistically generated to provide improved results in the hash function.

If they are not chosen at random (some constants are simply random primes), they are chosen to satisfy certain mathematical/probabilistic criteria. These numbers are often found by running some sort of simulation. In particular, these numbers appear to be derived from a [Simulated annealing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).